# Sql database running on many machines

Tags: sql, distributed-computing

Martin Fowler [mentions](https://youtu.be/qI_g07C_Q5I) that running relational sql database across many machines is an “unnatural act” as in its very difficult to do. But he doesn’t explain why.

What makes this so difficult?

Comment: One reason is that, since a table row on its own never represents even a single business entity, what do you do if two tables are on different machines? What effect does that workaround and the implied synchronization have on atomicity, on isolation, on consistency, on performance?

Answer (score 0):

**Its difficult but also common.**

There are many patterns to this
e.g.

1. master-slave or "read-replicas" where the master is used for read
   and write, and the changes are then passed to the slave(s)- the
   slaves are just used for reads. mysql & postgres can do this.
2. master-master - more difficult but can be implemented in many
   databases. writes can be done on any server in the cluster
3. "massively parallel processing" or "MPP" databases. Data is
   partitioned across multiple servers or nodes with each server/node
   having memory/processors to process data locally. Example Teradata,
   Greenplum Pivotal, Redshift, Vertica.